# how to run another .js file in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Need your help, can't figure out what's wrong with my code. Your help is much appreciated.

Firstly, I have a main index.js file where all my main code is and I want it to call another function from another file which is post.js and execute whatever I put in that file but I can't make it work. I have an error called undefined.

**index.js (Main File)**

```
var xxx = require('./post.js');

function handlepostWaterRequest(intent, session, callback) {

            var cardTitle = "Water"
            var speechOutput = "Ok!, Now watering plants!" + xxx.post;
            callback(session.attributes,
                buildSpeechletResponse(cardTitle, speechOutput, "", true)); 
}
```

**post.js (Second File)**

```
var ubidots = require('ubidots');
var client = ubidots.createClient('***API Key***');

module.exports = {
    post: client.auth(function () {
            var pumpData = this.getVariable('***Key***'); 
            pumpData.getValues(function (err, data) {       
                console.log("Uploading..............");
                pumpData.saveValue(0); 
            });
    })
};
```

How do I call the `xxx.post` properly and make it executable? 
Much thansks!

Comment: Do you have a StackTrace for the undefined error?

Comment: No, I do not have any slacktrace for the undefined error

Comment: I'm going to assume `client.auth....` is asynchronous and/or doesn't actually return anything. In which case `xxx.post` will be undefined. To get the value from an asynchronous function you'll most likely have to change the way your code works a little. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: `client.auth` does not return *anything* - hence your `undefind`: (see https://github.com/ubidots/ubidots-node/blob/master/lib/client.js )